# Is there any way to de-initialize the googleapiclient, facebook login sdk, etc in the onDestroy of my activity?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, facebook-login, google-signin

Startscreen of my project is having options for login with facebook and google. so i have initialised both the sdk's there. When I checked with leakcanary ,there is  a lot of memory leaks in the startscreen which in fact is due to these sdks.. how to catch these memory leaks?

Answer (score 0):

As for googlelogin, you should disconnect the google api client in **onStop()** method of the activity.

```
mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
```

So that it is disconnected even if the activity is in the backstack.
The onDestroy() is not reliable. Although it is advisable that you loose the reference to the object in the **onDestroy()** method.

```
mGoogleApiClient = null;
```

Comment: unfortunately, no :)

Comment: Maybe, you can call finish() on the activity where you initialized GoogleApiClient if you don't need it after you start the other activity.